# Android hot keywords (Trends)?

Tags: android, iphone, search, search-engine, google-play

Is there a way to find out what is being searched for on the Android market? For example if I want to find out how many people searched for a specific keyword a day. If there is a tool out there, it would be helpful to find out what people search for and make apps accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't provide this information.

But this might help :)

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-search-terms